# How to sort an ArrayList for a specific row without a parameter to differentiate from first to second entry in that specific element?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I am looking for a solution to sort the following ArrayList:

```
static ArrayList<Person> myPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();

Person pers = new Person(anrede, vorname, nachname, strasse, plz,
                    ort, telefon, fax, bemerkung);
myPersons.add(pers);
```

The list should be sorted with `nachname` as comparator. Yet I haven't found out how to set up a `compare(nachname1, nachname2)`. How can such a differentiation be implemented?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: `myPersons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getNachname));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work properly

```
myPersons.sort((Person p1, Person p2) -> p1.getNachname().compareTo(p2.getNachname()));
```